# Ext js licensing

Tags: javascript, licensing, extjs

We have a CMS which is licensed under Apache 2.0 license and is available on github. Now i want to use extjs to make some kind of table editor for the CMS. I won't modify anything of ext-js but i will write an extension using ext-js.

Now i was wondering which license to use for this. I'm a big noob when it comes to licensing and when i read the license info of extjs i didn't understand a word of it.

greets,
Daan

Comment: Why not write to the Ext.js people and ask them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1):

If your extension is considered a derivative work then my understanding is that it will be under the same license unless the license explicitly states that you can relicense the code (for example the BSD license).